# SaltStack virt module and LVMs

Tags: saltstack

This is just a quick question because I can't find the answer in the documentation. Is it possible to use Logical Volumes with [Salt Virt](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.virt.html) for [disk profiles](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/virt/disk.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, That's a limitation for Salt Virt. You may manage logical volumes using [Salt Linux_LVM](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.linux_lvm.html)